# apt (resilient)

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation

I need to install a package list. The problem is that if a package does not exist in the repository it simply stops. I need some alternative to apt where it just ignores when a package is not in the repository

Comment: What if the missing package is a dependency for one you want to install?

Comment: In my specific case this is not so relevant. And I will also notify the user!

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/837662/continue-on-error-when-apt-get-encounters-an-install-unable-to-locate-package-is

Answer (score 2):

`apt` will not continue on errors.

As a workaround, you can install each item separately:

```
for i in package1 package2 package3; do
  sudo apt-get install -y $i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xargs -n1 sudo apt install  < list
```

xargs can be used to install a list of package one by one.

man xargs;

```
       -n max-args, --max-args=max-args
          Use  at  most  max-args  arguments per command line.
```